# Google Apps Script - Cannot access function in library

Tags: function, google-apps-script

There is a function in a library I want to use.  I added the library and attempted to call the function using .();.  I get an error saying  is not a function.  I'm assuming it can't find it in the library,  but maybe there is another issue.  Any ideas?

I looked at a project another guy wrote and I have the same format and parameters.  His works, mine does not.

This is the function call:
SystemIntegrationsPadgett.refreshRhCsv_2(psaReportId, psaDataTab ,psaReportParms);

Here is the error:
Error
TypeError: SystemIntegrationsPadgett.refreshRhCsv_2 is not a function
onOpen  @ Utilization.gs:49

Below is a screenshot showing the library.

[image: screenshot showing the library]

Comment: Function name used is incorrect. Check for typos. Provide [mcve].

Comment: Share your code that is causing the error and maybe we can help.  You invoke library function by preceeding the function name with the library name.  For example `MyLibrary.functionName()`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  I'll post here just in case it helps somebody.  There were 3 versions of the library in addition to the head.  I was using version 1, the function name changed in version 3. Short answer, I needed to use version 3.